# Mail merge into Word template including child objects?

Tags: mail-merge

Is it possible to use standard Salesforce Mail Merge (with a Word template) from a Master object in a Master-Detail relationship to include information from the related Detail records, for example in a table?

I believe the answer is no; however, I'm curious because it seems possible to do this with Opportunity Line Items, and wondered if it is possible it can be applied more generally? If not, does anyone know the reasoning?

I know this can be done with Conga, Drawloop and other similar products, and I know Visualforce templates are also an option, but I am just wondering about standard, Word based templates.

Comment: I think the mail-merge tag is appropriate; which other tag(s) did you want to add?

Comment: Thanks Mike - for some reason, I couldn't find that tag when I was posting the question. A forest/trees moment maybe...

Answer (score 3):

Matt is right.  Oppty is treated as a special object in standard mail merge for the purposes of generating proposals or invoices.  You could potentially roll-up your detail data into fields on the parent object, but otherwise I'd recommend Conga.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, as far as I know, this is not possible with the standard mail merge, even extended mail merge. You can't pull from child objects without a third party tool.